# SSRS 2008 R2 copy an entire Tablix and paste to same report

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a table and want to put exactly the same table right next to it (but with the other dataset's data, i.e. previous years sales).

I would love to just be able to copy and paste the current tablix and then just change the name of the dataset that the tablix uses, but I cannot find a <kbd>Copy</kbd> function anywhere.

Does anyone know if it is possible to copy and paste an entire tablix in a report?

Comment: **Future Visitors**, if you're getting here because of the error `Report Builder was unable to paste successfully`, then check out the question [Copy and paste a table (tablix) in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25252424/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am taking it too simple.

[image]

Right Click on the are pointed and you should have a copy button there. Paste it anywhere you feel like, change the dataset name from the tablix properties and make sure the columns in the
second dataset are present in this tablix.

Comment: ok, I am NOT that stupid LOL  I absolutely did that, and several times -- but the Copy function (and Cut, for that matter) was greyed out so I was not able to select it!  :)  I just did it again and it allowed me to copy.  I SWEAR it would not let me (or I wouldn't have posted a question LOL).  Thanks and so sorry for the question, I don't know why it wasn't an option before... :-O

Comment: @KimJones, please accept answers that answer questions you've asked on StackOverflow