# Copy and paste a table (tablix) in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that has data for one day, and I need to have the same data at the bottom but in 3 different lines.  I'd like to copy the main day table 3 times at the bottom, and then use different datasets for each one.

I tried copying the tablix and pasting it into the `Body` beneath the tablix, but I get the following error:

> Report Builder was unable to paste successfully.

How can I accomplish the copy and paste? Or if that isn't possible, is there another way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Here's an animated screenshot:

[image: Example]

Comment: Hey, this is happens because VS doesn't rename textboxes with expr on the fly, and that is why u have this error, but yet I didn't find a solution for that, did u?

Comment: upvoted because of the animated screenshot!!!

Answer (score 31):

You are likely getting the error message `Report Builder was unable to paste successfully` because somewhere in the grid there is a cell that uses Custom Code From the Report

> i.e. you cannot copy a textbox with this custom code: “Code.MyCustomeCode()”
>    - [Report Builder was unable to paste successfully](http://mibuso.com/blogs/clausl/2014/09/05/report-builder-was-unable-to-paste-successfully/)

This has been a reported bug since SSRS 2008:

> When using Visual Studio 2008 to create new reports, we cannot copy and paste multiple textboxes in a tablix, and receive a popup error stating "Report Builder was unable to paste successfully"
>    - [Unable to copy and paste textboxes in SSRS reports with Custom Code after 2008 R2 SP2 upgrade](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767968/)

**Workaround**:

1. **Open up the XML** view for the report, either in Visual Studio by right clicking the report and selecting *View Code*, or by editing in any text editor.
2. **Comment out `Code.`** blocks.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> your way through the document looking for `Code.`.  The goal is to preserve the code in some way, while temporarily commenting out the line.  Depending on your actual code, this might be different, but I here's what I like to do:

   - *Find*:               `=Code.`
   - *Replace With*: `='Code.`
3. Go back to the Designer View and **Copy and Paste the Tablix**.  You can do this by right clicking the top left corner of the tablix control:
   [image: Copy Tablix]
4. Go back to the XML View and **reverse the find and replace**

   - *Find*:                `='Code.`
   - *Replace With*: `=Code.`

You should be all set!

> **Note**: You cannot just copy the `<tablix>` block in the XML view after step 1 because it will create elements with the same exact `name` property

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, you can just add a comment AFTER your code like so:

```
'custom code comment
```

Then you can copy and paste it as normal, without having to remove your comment afterwards or comment out your code beforehand.

Comment: Wow, how did you figure this out? Thanks heaps!!

Comment: @sasfrog Wish I could take credit for it, but it was just a ton of copies where some worked and others failed. Took a lot of trial and error figuring out what it was.

Comment: This is old, but this is fantastic to know. Real time saver.

Comment: Do you add this after the actual code block for the report, or in the expression that uses the code?

Comment: Add the comment in the expression itself. I just tried it on a tablix having like 10 code calls and voila, I was able to copy/paste it once I threw in a dummy comment on the end. Great find!!

Comment: T H A N K    Y O U!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, and I noticed that this bug occurred when there is a Code reference anywhere in the report, and is not limited to the copied fields.

Answer (score 0):

In the last case, if nothing works for you:

1. You can copy and paste the tale(Tablix 1 to tablix2)
2. Delete all custom expressions in the new tablix (tablix2)
3. Get inside each textbox tablix1, copy the code
4. Get inside the new textbox (tablix2) and paste

I know it seems too much work, but it can help.